# Android Studio fails to debug with Error:Execution failed for task ':app:preDexDebug'.Pl

Tags: android, sdk, android-support-library, android-studio-2.1

When I run my project, it shows the error in the title. What is the solution?

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.bangloss.boss.myapplication"
    minSdkVersion 10
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.1.1'
}
```

Comment: Please format your code properly.

Comment: call `compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"` and set `targetSdkVersion 23`